# How to correctly implement drawing application without high allocation of RAM

Tags: android, graphics, paint

I have created a drawing application in android and was wondering, what is the correct way to draw on canvas while been concise of RAM allocation.

I have noticed that when the number of paths or points within the paths become too large, delays in `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` become apparent. It is obvious there is a solution to this, but I am looking for the standard way to solve this.

I have not found much information online, but I am currently trying to save the current `canvas` to a `Bitmap` and then setting my `View` for the `canvas` (`LinearLayout`).

I am currently trying the following, but it is not setting the `LinearLayout` to the `Background`:

```
public Bitmap saveTempCanvas() {
        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        this.buildDrawingCache();
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getDrawingCache());
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bmp;
    }
//. . .
//. . .
Drawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), pv.saveTempCanvas());
LinearLayoutCanvas.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
```

Is this the standard way to create an `"Paint"` activity? 
Why is the following code not working to set the `BitmapDrawable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling this function in onDraw() each time, I am not surprised why it is more and more laggy. Here is my approach and it works well:

```
public class TouchEventView extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();
    Bitmap bitMap;
    Canvas myCanvas;
    Canvas defaultCanvas;

    public TouchEventView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);        
    }

    public TouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();

        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.BEVEL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        myCanvas = new Canvas(bitMap);
        defaultCanvas = canvas;
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        myCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        myCanvas.setBitmap(bitMap);
        myCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            performClick();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        super.performClick();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not calling this method inside of the `onDraw(Canvas c)` method. This is only called intermittently outside of the `onDraw()` method.